# Gitlab pages and Jekyll - issue with set up TLS Lets Encrypted

Tags: ssl, jekyll, gitlab, gitlab-ci, lets-encrypt

I try to add SSL/TLS on my static web site. I use Gitlab static pages, and Jekyll is for content.
I follow this instructions to set up TLS - [Gitlab tutorial](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/04/11/tutorial-securing-your-gitlab-pages-with-tls-and-letsencrypt/).

I am stack on this part - I got 404 error from Gitlab pages

> Once the build finishes, test again if everything is working well:
>
> ```
> # Note that we're using the actual domain, not localhost anymore
> $ curl http://YOURDOMAIN.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM
> ```

The problem is next
I am successfully generated certificate with command `./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a manual -d example.com`
I created custom page `letsencrypt-setup.html` in root directory whit appropriate content.

I run `jekyll build` command and it created `_site/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM.html` page.
When I run `curl` command to this page it worked with and without `.html` extension - both commands work, and return appropriate value

```
curl http://localhost:4000/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM
curl http://localhost:4000/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM.html
```

When I commit changes and push to Gitlab after build and deploy I can fetch appropriate content only with second command

```
curl http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM.html
```

When I ran

```
curl http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM
```

I got 404 error.

If I press continue in `./letsencrypte` script I also got 404 error. This tool try against URL without `.html` extension.

I read comments in the tutorial and try this [workaround](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/04/11/tutorial-securing-your-gitlab-pages-with-tls-and-letsencrypt/#comment-2638827520) but it didn't work for me.

I have no clue what to try next - I have no lot experience with Jekyll/SSL

Comment: It doesn't exactly answer the question, but I solved the problem by using the DNS challenge instead of the http one: `./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a manual -d mydomain.com --preferred-challenge dns` it saved me from trying to figure out the gitlab stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what I did was that I copied the challenge file after the build finished on gitlab, since I could not figure out how to make jekyll omit the file extension.

my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: ruby:2.3

pages:
  script:
  - gem install jekyll
  - jekyll build -d public
  # Use this when creating a new letsencrypt cert, this since jekyll adds .html to the file and letsencrypd does not expect a .html extension
  - cp ./public/.well-known/acme-challenge/HASHFILE-FROM-LETSENCRYPT.html ./public/.well-known/acme-challenge/HASHFILE-FROM-LETSENCRYPT
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: I tried with symlink (`ln -s`), but it doesn't work. Copy works.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution (as [suggested by Marthym](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/04/11/tutorial-securing-your-gitlab-pages-with-tls-and-letsencrypt/#comment-3264642622)) is simply to add a slash to the end of the permalink line:

```
permalink: /.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM/
```

In this way, visiting YOURDOMAIN.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/... will redirect you to YOURDOMAIN.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/...**/** (note the extra slash) which will have the correct data. It worked flawlessly for me, and I didn't need to update the .gitlab-ci.yml when I switched to a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra slash didn't work for me. I had to add '/index.html'.

> permalink: /.well-known/acme-challenge/${CHALLENGE}/index.html